# Binary Classification problem for imbalanced dataset

Tags: r, classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I am new to machine learning and need help. I have a dataset with two classes(0,1) where is 0 is Profitable and 1 is Unprofitable. Ratio of 0:1 in train set is 150/52

Taking *positive as "1"(Unprofitable)* and *negative as 0(Profitable)*,False Negative cost is 4900 and False Positive cost is 4000.
Objective is to maximize f(profit) = 4000*(No of True Negative-No of False Positive)-(4900*No of False Negative) such that is atleast > 1775$(base profit without any model)

With EDA I figured Years At employer, Debt/Income Ratio and Age to be most important predictors.
With XGBoost having scale_pos_weight =3 I get excellent results on training set but fails badly (overfits) on test set.

No matter how much I try I am not able to improve Profits for test set beyond 1375\$ (as mentioned above needs to be at least > 1775$)

Even rpart with loss function does not help much... Can anyone please provide any input?

However **If I take an alternative approach (i.e take only observations with Years at employer <20)** and then apply glm or rpart results are really great on both train and test set, but is this approach even right ? (I did this because EDA shows that all unprofitable customers were with "years at employer <20",in train set)

Comment: Maybe dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235808/binary-classification-with-strongly-unbalanced-classes, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the base profit without any model is truly the best one can do. Compare [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352), and tangentially related [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352)

If your alternative approach works in production, then it works. There is little "right" or "wrong" here. Do you automatically classify everyone with <20 years tenure as "unprofitable"? Note that "all unprofitable customers had <20 years tenure" is *not* the same as "everyone with <20 years tenure is unprofitable"!

[My answer to "Classification probability threshold"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your input . No I do not automatically classify everyone with <20 years as Unprofitable. I just took subset where Year of exp was less than 20 and then build the model, to predict profitable/Unprofitable