# Over sampling for minority classes

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, oversampling

I'm a bit confused with the idea of over/under sampling. People have mentioned that rotations are a good technique. By rotation, do they literally mean rotate the image by a few degrees and then add it as another training point for the minority class?

also how are we supposed to even out the ratios? assuming that

class 1 has 1000 points

class 2 has 700 points

class 3 has 40 points

and we should assume similar distribution in the test set.

My conv net always predicts class 1 during training and fails the testing phase.

Comment: He and Garcia have a great paper titled "Learning from imbalanced datasets" that may answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> By rotation, do they literally mean rotate the image by a few degrees and then add it as another training point for the minority class?

Yes, though it can the done for other classes as well.

For example, http://benanne.github.io/2014/04/05/galaxy-zoo.html did the following data augmentation tricks:

> #### Exploiting spatial invariances
>
> Images of galaxies are rotation invariant: there is no up or down in
>   space. They are also scale invariant and translation invariant to a
>   limited extent. All of these invariances could be exploited to do
>   **data augmentation**: creating new training data by perturbing the existing data points.
>
> Each training example was perturbed before presenting it to the
>   network by randomly scaling it, rotating it, translating it and
>   optionally flipping it. I used the following parameter ranges:
>
> - **rotation**: random with angle between 0° and 360° (uniform)
> - **translation**: random with shift between -4 and 4 pixels (relative to the original image size of 424x424) in the x and y direction
>     (uniform)
> - **zoom**: random with scale factor between 1/1.3 and 1.3 (log-uniform)
> - **flip**: yes or no (bernoulli)
>
> Because both the initial downsampling to 69x69 and the random
>   perturbation are affine transforms, they could be **combined into one
>   affine transformation step** (I used scikit-image for this). This sped
>   up things significantly and reduced information loss.
>
> #### Colour perturbation
>
> After this, the colour of the images was changed as described in
>   [Krizhevsky et al.
>   2012](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf), with two
>   differences: the first component had a much larger eigenvalue than the
>   other two, so only this one was used, and the standard deviation for
>   the scale factor alpha was set to 0.5.
>
> #### "Realtime" augmentation
>
> Combining downsampling and perturbation into a single affine transform
>   made it possible to do data augmentation in realtime, i.e. during
>   training. This significantly reduced overfitting because the network
>   would never see the exact same image twice. While the network was
>   being trained on a chunk of data on the GPU, the next chunk would be
>   generated on the CPU in multiple processes, to ensure that all the
>   available cores were used.
>
> #### Centering and rescaling
>
> I experimented with centering and rescaling the galaxy images based on
>   parameters extracted with
>   [sextractor](https://www.astromatic.net/software/sextractor). Although
>   this didn't improve performance, including a few models that used it
>   in the final ensemble helped to increase variance (see "Model
>   averaging" for more information).
>
> I extracted the **center** of the galaxies, as well as the **Petrosian
>   radius**. A number of different radii can be extracted, but the
>   Petrosian radius seemed to give the best size estimate. I then
>   centered each image by shifting the estimated center pixel to (212,
>   212), and rescaled it so that its Petrosian radius would be equal to
>   160 pixels. The scale factor was limited to the range (1/1.5, 1.5),
>   because there were some outliers.
>
> This rescaling and centering could also be collapsed into the affine
>   transform doing downsampling and perturbation, so it did not slow
>   things down at all.

Given that class 2 is also misclassified by your network, the issue doesn't seem to be fully a class imbalance issue. The choice of the ratio depends on a few factors such as how much weight you want to give to each class. FYI  [Opinions about Oversampling in general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/234016/12359).